# Running forever for NodeJs from rc.local

Tags: node.js, embedded-linux, forever

I want NodeJs server to start at boot and be sure it stays up if it crashes with forever.

I've read a lot of posts on how to do it and the possible issues associated with it.
The problem is that I have a limited memory available on given machine so I'm forced to "contain" NodeJs.

Reading the forever documentation I found out that it can be done using the command:

```
forever start -c "node --max_old_space_size=512" myapp.js
```

In this way forever calls the node server passing the memory argument which, in this case, limits the heap to 512 MB.
So I wrote my sh script for rc.local like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /forever_bin_dir
./forever start -c "node --max_old_space_size=512" /myapp_dir/myapp.js
```

Since rc.local works with limited environmental variables, "node" can't be find and the script fails.

I even tried with Cron adding to its file the line:

```
@reboot /forever_bin_dir/forever start -c "node --max_old_space_size=512" /myapp_dir/myapp.js
```

But the same issue persist.

My question is: how can i run forever at boot time passing at the same time the argument about memory ?

Comment: did you try running the command without `forever`?

Comment: To be honest no, since I need forever. I tried the script to launch Node.Js on boot but without the memory constraint and it works.

Comment: try to run node manually with the memory constrains

Comment: It works manually with memory constraints. I did not try it in rc.local tho.

Comment: WARNING
If your command runs continuously (perhaps runs an infinite loop) or is likely not to exit, you must be sure to fork the process by adding an ampersand to the end of the command https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md

Comment: Of course, but I don’t need to run it on a different terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found It's just setting the PATH inside a script.

I created a sh script in the home folder called launchforever.sh
I got the environmental variables using the #printenv command.

The launchforever script is something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=<copied from printenv>:$PATH
forever start -c "node --max_old_space_size=30" > /dev/null
```

After saving I gave it the permissions:

```
#chmod 700 /home/<user>/launchforever.sh
```

Then I added it to Cron:

```
#crontab -u <user> -e
```

And inside its file I added:

```
@reboot /home/<user>/launchforever.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/jinze/3748766#file-forever-initd-example-sh) init script used for same purpose starting Node script forever.